# обновить год, цвет и свойства цены, которые третий получил от параметра объекта

Tags: функции

`updateCar` - должно получить 3 параметра, первые два обозначают модель, а третий должен получить объект. Объект должен иметь год, цвет и цену. Функция должна найти объект, соответствующий марке , модели автомобилей из автомобилей, обновить год, цвет и свойства цены, которые она получила от третьего параметра объекта.

```
var cars = {
    0: {
        mark: "BMW",
        model: "E90",
        year: 2008,
        color: "red",
        price: '$7000'
    },
    1: {
        mark: "Ford",
        model: "focus",
        year: 2010,
        color: "black",
        price: '$6300',
    },
    2: {
        mark: "Honda",
        model: "elyson",
        year: 2012,
        color: "blue",
        price: '$5500',
    },
    3: {
        mark: "Honda",
        model: "elyson",
        year: 2009,
        color: "blue",
        price: '$6300',
    },
    4: {
        mark: "Nissa",
        model: "tida",
        year: 2009,
        color: "red",
        price: '$4500',
    }
}
var infoCar = {
    year: 2022,
    color: "black",
    price: '$5500',
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Если верно понял условие вопроса, то на JavaScript'е будет примерно так:

```js
let cars = {
  0: {
    mark: "BMW",
    model: "E90",
    year: 2008,
    color: "red",
    price: '$7000'
  },
  1: {
    mark: "Ford",
    model: "focus",
    year: 2010,
    color: "black",
    price: '$6300',
  },
  2: {
    mark: "Honda",
    model: "elysion",
    year: 2012,
    color: "blue",
    price: '$5500',
  },
  3: {
    mark: "Honda",
    model: "elysion",
    year: 2009,
    color: "blue",
    price: '$6300',
  },
  4: {
    mark: "Nissan",
    model: "tiida",
    year: 2009,
    color: "red",
    price: '$4500',
  }
}
let infoCar = {
  year: 2022,
  color: "black",
  price: '$5500',
}

console.log(cars);

function updateCar(mark, model, info) {
  for (let car in cars) {
    if (cars[car].mark == mark && cars[car].model == model) {
      cars[car].year = info.year;
      cars[car].color = info.color;
      cars[car].price = info.price;
    }
  }
}

updateCar("Honda", "elysion", infoCar);

console.log(cars);
```

P.S. С вашего позволения поправил опечатки в названии "Nissan", "tiida" и "elysion"